# System32 folder in windows 7

Tags: vb.net, 32bit-64bit, system32, syswow64

I'm using this code in XP 32-bit OS to get the `%windir%\windows\system32` folder path.

```
sysFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
```

What I want to know is that will this same code return the `%windir%\windows\syswow64` folder when used in Windows 7 (64/32-bit)?

Answer (score 5):

It will return c:\windows\system32, even in a 32-bit program that runs on the 64-bit version of Windows.  Do *not* fix this, it doesn't need fixing.  Because when you *use* that path, Windows will automatically remap it to c:\windows\syswow64.  The [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx) takes care of it.

Comment: @ Hans Passant +1 for your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my Windows7 box with .NET 4.0

This code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86));
```

Prints the following from both 32- and 64-bit process:

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  On my Windows 7 64-bit box, targeting x64:

```
C:\Windows\system32
```